# Silverlight: Changing color of all buttons in the application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am new to silverlight. I would like to know how to change the color all the buttons in my application to gray. Is there any way to define a user control that inherits from Button class and then use that globally as done in windows forms?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

inside you `App.XAML` add a style for button

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </Style>
 </Application.Resources>
```

Now when you will declare a button in let's say in MainWindow, its background color will be Gray

```
 <Button Content="Sample Button"/>
```

Comment: Can you share your `App.XAML` and `XAML` where you have declared `button`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file themes/generic.xaml and put your button style there:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
</Style>
```